# How to detect all kind of scrolling without libraries?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mousewheel, autoscroll

I want to know how can I detect a scroll event on page Here are two different ways to scroll.

On desktop:

1. By rolling the mouse wheel (the event handler is `DOMElement.onwheel` event handler).
2. By pressing the mouse wheel and moving the cursor in appropriate direction (known also as autoscroll).

On mobile:

1. by swapping the finger down or up

How can I detect the scroll event as described in the second and third way?

Comment: *and move the cursor above or beyond* - What does that mean?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button) they explain the mouse events.

Comment: @Script47 it means when you click on mouse wheel a scroll img is placed where you clicked and for scroll down you move mouse beyond the img and same thing for above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all cases it is a `scroll` event, so:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  ...
});
```

Second and third events have one thing in common - they occur inside `mousedown` and `mouseup` frame. You can use that for event flavor detection.